# Reserved pointer addresses (using as special cases)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-address

Is it secure to do the following?

```
MyClass* p = WantItInCase1();
if (p == NULL)
    p = 0x1;
else
   p = WantItInCase2();
if (p == NULL)
   p = 0x2;
...
CheckCases (p);  // we check '0x1' and '0x2' cases and otherwise process 'p' as normal object
```

I have a situation where `MyClass` objects can't handle all variants needed in `CheckCases()`. So to avoid additional parameter is it possible to use this approach? At least I need a range of addresses that can't be used for `new` allocations.

--- Update ---

Taking in account answers I decided to make some 'tricky' approach:

```
// somewhere in global definitions:
const MyClass* P_CASE_1 = (MyClass*) new int;
const MyClass* P_CASE_2 = (MyClass*) new int;
...
// previous code piece:
MyClass* p = WantItInCase1();
if (p == NULL)
    p = P_CASE_1;
```

It would be memory-safe, and it's not dangerous to leak 4 bytes for each `P_CASE_#`.

Comment: Honestly, this approach sounds like a nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: You should just use another variable for state, you're mixing data into `p` which is totally unrelated.

Comment: I really don't understand why you are doing this, but I agree with @Moo-Juice. Certainly 'secure' isn't something that comes in to play here, valid maybe but you are mixing memory addresses with state information which I'd strongly recommend against.

Comment: The non-null pointer returned from WantItInCase1 is overwritten by the pointer returned from WantItInCase2 - this might be a memory leak! Also, I'd look to refactor the code into something easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the OS :-)

To make it clear: on Windows 32 bits the last gb of address space is always reserved for the kernel, so you can use its addresses for your use. Normally it would be the last 2 gb of address space, but through a switch [/3GB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can change it. A similar trick is used in the kernel for some data structures.

I wouldn't ever do it :-)

I'll add that probably 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 are pretty safe, because the addresses given to you by the OS are normally at least 32 bits aligned, the 0x0 is defined for special purpose so the next three bytes won't be allocated in a memory block. Aaah... Too much difficult to explain. Let's say that the C runtime takes the memory from the OS, and that "standard" OS won't ever give memory in the 0x0-0x3 range.

Answer (score 2):

With GCC this kind of assigment are "by default" forbidden. You will have to force the compilation thanks to the flag -fpermissive.

I think that it is not "nice". I prefer this kind of approach :

```
MyClass* p = WantItInCase1();
int flag;
if (p == NULL)
    flag = 0x1;
else
   p = WantItInCase2();
if (p == NULL)
   flag = 0x2;
...
CheckCases (flag);
```

Of course more "memory" is used, but today, what is 4 bytes ?

So to reply to your question, this kind of assignments are very discouraged... But your program may work...

If you try to read p (in your checkclass method), you will write something like :

```
if(p == 0x1) ...
```

This kind of line will generate a warning (with GCC) because you compare a pointer to an integer, so : One warning + -fpermissive flag = Don't do that !

Comment: In terms of design I stand for additional flag. But in my case `p` is passed through many methods while reaches `CheckCases` and I want to do minimum code changes.

Comment: Maybe you can add a flag as a member of "MyClass", and construct a valid MyClass in every "Case".
Then you just have a look to MyClass.flag ...

Answer (score 0):

This is implementation specific. On Microsoft compilers targetting Windows it will work. The `MAKEINTRESOURCE` macro does essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not only undefined behavior, but highly platform specific, as such it should really be avoid, which you could do with a custom reference counted pointer (where a negative reference is used for your special cases), or a auxiliary variable or even some fancy `do{}while(0)` constructs.

If you really do want to tag the pointers, the first page (64Kb) under windows is reserved and will never be allocated in user space or kernel. same goes for the MSB of the address, which is reserved for kernel space. You will need to do some casting however, for that `uintptr_t` will do nicely.